# clear browsing cache - basic html css js website

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a simple HTML, SASS, JS website and each time im uploading new files, to actually see the changes appear on the website I need to clear my browsing data.

is there anyway to address it via vanilla js headers, or a button on the website to clear cache?

Comment: Where are you hosting the site? What backend is serving it? Need more info

Comment: It has no backend, it is a very simple website using html, js, css straight forward

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **button** that deletes the cache for that page like this :

```
<button>Clear cache </button>
```

```
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    window.location.reload(true);  
    window.location.reload();  // few browsers don't require for a parameter to be passed

})
```

To know more about [window.location.reload(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: The argument only works in Firefox. From your link: "However, in all other browsers, any parameter you specify in a location.reload() call will be ignored and have no effect of any kind."

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hritik Sharma, I'll try and apply that.
Thank you for your addition Phix.